# Ubuntu 12.04 won't boot at all for the first time

Tags: dual-boot

So I tried installing Ubuntu for the first time today, and it installed all well, but then it froze at the 'Preparing to run Ubuntu for the first time...' screen.

I then proceeded to restart my computer and load Ubuntu from the OS selection screen. My screen completely froze and the picture didn't even come up fully as if my video driver was not installed correctly.

Are there any fixes to this problem? Would greatly appreciate it.

Possible useful information:

- Using http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer
- Dual-booting with Windows

Comment: I am not sure if these answers will apply to the situation of the Wubi installer, but there are many strategies to fix a "black screen on boot" at http://askubuntu.com/q/162075/

Answer (score -1):

I prefer not to use wubi (the windows installer). It has a lot of issues like no hibernation, slower data I/O rate, etc.

Download the Ubuntu iso.
Create a partition in Windows allocating at least 20 GB HDD space for Linux.
Boot into live and click on Install icon on the desktop. Then select the install alongside Windows option and follow the on-screen instructions.

NOTE: Your default bootloader (BOOTMGR) will be replaced by GRUB. You can always remove Ubuntu. Install EasyBCD on your Windows and in the deployment section, select 'Write to MBR'. Then format the Linux partition.